# How to make a View's Height Dynamic

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, custom-cell

**The code is:**

```
View v = convertView;

LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newsfeed_custom_listview_facebook, parent, false);

TextView username = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.username);
TextView prayerTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.prayerTitle);
TextView createdOn = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.createdOn);
TextView prayerMessage = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.prayerMessage);
ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) v.findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
MixedObj menuItemsBean = menuItems.get(position);
RoundedImageView img = (RoundedImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);

username.setText(menuItemsBean.name);
prayerTitle.setText(menuItemsBean.title);
createdOn.setText(menuItemsBean.created_on);

TextView textView = new TextView(context);


//prayerMessage.setText(menuItemsBean.message);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new 
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.image);
 textView.setLayoutParams(p);
 textView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
 textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
 //textView.setText(menuItemsBean.message);
String message = "please God forgive me for all my mistakes i have ever done in my life please God forgive me for all my mistakes i have ever done in my life please God forgive me for all my mistakes i have ever done in my life please God forgive me for all my mistakes i have ever done in my life please God forgive me for all my mistakes i have ever done in my life please God forgive me for all my mistakes i have ever done in my life please God forgive me for all my mistakes i have ever done in my life please God forgive me for all my mistakes i have ever done in my life please God forgive me for all my mistakes i have ever done in my life end";

 message = menuItemsBean.message;
 textView.setText(message);

 ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) v;
 viewGroup.addView(textView);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
textView.getLayoutParams();

AbsListView.LayoutParams layoutParams = (AbsListView.LayoutParams)  

viewGroup.getLayoutParams();
//layoutParams.height += ();
 return v;
```

I want to Change Height of a Custom view Inflated for a `listView`. 
I have tried this but its not working I want a different height on every cell depended upon the message `TextView` Size.

Anyone please Help..

Comment: Let me know, about solution below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of your realization it's basics of ListView. 
From base object, ListView invokes just single size for all views, and invalidate every action. For your task you need to use your own list. For ex.

**1) 
Using several layouts:**

```
<ScrollView>
   <LinearLayout>
      //Add in loop all your views in code above!
   </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**2) 
Using LinkedListView:**

This view like ListView, but contains link to every views, which you added, and doesn't invalidate them. So you can use this, and more than simple ListView - you may changes any views in runtime without artifacts. Check this list on [Github - LinkedListView](https://github.com/GensaGames/LinkedListView)

**UPDATE:**

Using LinkedListView, just import to your project. Than create adapter

```
public class YourAdapter extends LinkedListView.Adapter  {

    private Context mainContext;
    private LinkedList<View> mainViewList;

    public CirclePagerAdapter (Context mainContext) {
        this.mainContext = mainContext;
        mainViewList = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    //CALL THIS TO ADD YOUR OWN VIEW
    public void addSimpleView (View v) {
        mainViewList.add(v)
        notifyDatasetChanged();
    }


    //CALL THIS TO DELETE VIEW
    public void deleteView(int index) {
        mainViewList.remove(index);
        notifyDatasetChanged();
    }

    @Override
        public View getObjectView(int position) {
        if (position < mainViewList.size())
            return mainViewList.get(position);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getObjectCount() {
        return mainViewList.size();
 }
```

After creating adapter call in your Activity!

```
LinkedListView listView = new LinkedListView (getContext());
LinkedListView.Adapter adapter = new MyBaseAdapter ();
listview.setViewPager(adapter);
```

Work pretty well!